# How to compare two directories and their files in perl

Tags: perl, file, compare, directory

Fred here again with a little issue I'm having that I hope you guys can help me with.

I'm reviewing for midterms and going over an old file I found on here and I wanted to get it working. I can't find it on here anymore but I still have the source code so I'll make another question on it.

So here was his assignment:
Write a perl script that will compare two directories for differences in regular files. All regular files with the same names should be tested with the unix function /usr/bin/diff -q which will determine whether they are identical. A file in dir1 which does not have a similarly named file in dir2 will have it's name printed after the string <<< while a file in dir2 without a corresponding dir1 entry will be prefixed with the string >>>. If two files have the same name but are different then the file name will be surrounded by > <.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use File::Basename;

@files1 = `/usr/bin/find $ARGV[0] -print`;
chop @files1;
@files2 = `/usr/bin/find $ARGV[1] -print`;
chop @files2;

statement:
for ($i=1; @files1 >= $i; $i++) {
    for ($x=1; @files2 >= $x; $x++) {

        $file1 = basename($files1[$i]);
        $file2 = basename($files2[$x]);

        if ($file1 eq $file2) {
            shift @files1;
            shift @files2;
            $result = `/usr/bin/diff -q $files1[$i] $files2[$x]`;
            chop $result;

            if ($result eq "Files $files1[$i] and $files2[$x] differ") {
                print "< $file1 >\n";
                next statement;
        } else {
                print "> $file1 <\n";
            }
        } else  {
            if ( !-e "$files1[$i]/$file2") { print ">>> $file2\n";}
            unless ( -e "$files2[$x]/$file1") { print "<<< $file1\n";}
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
> file2 <
>>> file5
<<< file1
```

The output should be:

```
> file1 <
> file2 <
<<< file4
>>> file5
```

I already checked the files to make sure that they all match and such but still having problems. If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, always use these:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

It comes with a short learning curve, but they more than make up for it in the long run.

Some notes:

- You should use the [`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) module instead of using a system call.
- You start your loops at array index 1. In perl, the first array index is 0. So you skip the first element.
- Your loop condition is wrong. `@files >= $x` means you will iterate to 1 more than max index (normally). You want either `$x < @files` or `$x <= $#files`.
- You should use `chomp`, which is a safer version of `chop`.
- Altering the arrays you are iterating over is a sure way to cause yourself some confusion.
- Why use `if (! -e ...)` and then `unless (-e ...)`? That surely just adds confusion.

And this part:

```
$file1 = basename($files1[$i]);
...
if ( !-e "$files1[$i]/$file2" )
```

Assuming `@files1` contains file names and not just directories, this will never match anything. For example:

```
$file2 = basename("dir/bar.html");
$file1 = basename("foo/bar.html"); 
-e "foo/bar.html/bar.html";         # does not compute
```

---

I would recommend using hashes for the lookup, assuming you only want to match against identical file names and missing file names:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my (%files1, %files2);
my ($dir1, $dir2) = @ARGV;

find( sub { -f && $files1{$_} = $File::Find::name }, $dir1);
find( sub { -f && $files2{$_} = $File::Find::name }, $dir2);

my @all = uniq(keys %files1, keys %files2);

for my $file (@all) {
    my $result;
    if ($files1{$file} && $files2{$file}) { # file exists in both dirs
        $result = qx(/usr/bin/diff -q $files1{$file} $files2{$file});
        # ... etc
    } elsif ($files1{$file}) {              # file only exists in dir1
    } else {                                # file only exists in dir2
    }
}
```

In the `find()` subroutine, `$_` represents the base name, and `$File::Find::name` the name including path (which is suitable for use with `diff`). The `-f` check will assert that you only include regular files in your hash.