# Rename the dir once update is finished - perl

Tags: perl

**Platform - Windows7**

I am looking for a script that will change the name of the latest modified directory :

Here is how I am getting the latest modified directory :

```
my $epoch_timestamp = (stat("logdir"))[9];
@date=localtime($epoch_timestamp);
$date[5] +=1900;
$date[4] +=1;
print "$date[5]-$date[4]-$date[3] $date[2]:$date[1]:$date[0]\n";
```

exp : `c:/dir_name/renamedir`

I have a folder `c:/dir_name`; inside that I am copying one folder after another. I need to change the name of the folder which has been copied completely.

`c:/dir_name/renamedir1`
`c:/dir_name/renamedir2`

The issue I am facing : 
I need to change the name once update is finished, i.e. after all the files have been copied in the dir.

So can anybody let me know how come we can be sure that all the files got copied in the folder?

Comment: More detail is needed in your question - as it is, we can't tell what you're asking.

Comment: i have added some more info ,hope that will help.

Comment: to rename a directory, take a look at move in File::Copy ( http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.4/lib/File/Copy.pm ). Other than that, not sure what the question is, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this way:

```
 use File::Copy;

 my $origDir = 'C:\dir_name\renamedir1\file1.txt';
 my $desDir = 'C:\dir_name\renamedir2\file1.txt';

 #Check whether the files copied or not 
 copy($origDir, $desDir) || die "Couldn't able to copy the files: $!";
```

On the Other way try to compare the folders/subfolder/files. And get reference from the below link:

[How to compare two directories and their files in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214172/how-to-compare-two-directories-and-their-files-in-perl)